# Why does my wifi speed improve on all wirelessly connected devices when I connect my laptop to the router using wire?

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a 25mbps internet connection. Scenario 1: no wired device connected to the router. In this case I get around 5mbps of internet speed on my phone which is wirelessly connected to the router.

Scenario 2: A laptop is connected to the router using ethernet wire. In this case I get around 20mbps of speed on my phone which is still connected wirelessly to the router.

Comment: I did misinterpret your question, so I deleted my answer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: What happens if the laptop is not connected to Ethernet, but completely powered off? I'm trying to understand if this is about two wireless devices failing to share wireless airtime well, or about something stranger going on.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless spectrum is shared.  I posit your laptop was making frequent connection to the Internet - and as it has bigger antennas it, in effect, took priority.  When this happened your cellphone connection lost packets, which the TCP protocol uses as a signal to slow down - so it did.

Its also possible something "buggy" was going on, like an error related to handling bandwidth use of wide channels. Its also possible (but, I think quite unlikely) that there is something that amounts to QoS on the router WiFi interface.